# Integration of Python console into a GUI C++ application

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, user-interface, integration

I'm going to add a python console widget (into a C++ GUI) below some other controls:
[image: Python Console screenshot]

Many classes are going to be exposed to the python code, including some access to GUI (maybe I'll consider PyQt).

> Should I run the Python code in a separate thread?

I think it's a good approach, because GUI won't be frozen while executing long commands. But on the other hand, shouldn't other controls be disabled to preserve objects' state and avoid conflicts?

Comment: The picture alone is worth +1. The question is good, too, though.

Comment: Yeah, the pic is kind of inspiring!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're apparently wanting to embed a Python interpreter to use Python as a scripting language in a what seems to be a Qt application, I suggest you have a look at [PythonQt](https://mevislab.github.io/pythonqt/).

With the PythonQt module, Python scripts will be able to interact with the GUI of your host application.

> Unlike PyQt and Qt Jambi, PythonQt is not designed to provide support for developers writing standalone applications. Instead, it provides facilities to embed a Python interpreter and focuses on making it easy to expose parts of the application to Python.

If I understood your needs correctly, that's all you need.

[PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) and [PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python) (officially supported by Nokia) aim at accessing Qt features from a Python program by providing bindings.

It's possible to embed PyQt in your application ([even a Qt application](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbedingPyQtTutorial)) and your Python scripts will be able to provide their own GUI while interacting with your application scripting API.

About thread safety, Qt offers a thread-safe way of posting events, and signal-slot connections across threads.

References:

- [Embedding Python into Qt Applications](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq23-pythonqt.html).
- [Notes for embedding python in your C/C++ app](https://web.archive.org/web/20230203003624/https://vedanamedia.com/2008/11/22/notes-for-embedding-python-in-your-cc-app/)
- [EmbedingPyQtTutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbedingPyQtTutorial)