# Integrating CMD Module with PYQT

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, cmd, pyqt4

I am developing a texteditor using PYQT, the text editor is used for processing a DSL, one that I am making up. Now I would really like to have the ability to click on on an ICON, say a console icon in my gui toolbar that will launch a console, from the console I could run my custom commands that allow me to do things like manipulate my SQLITE database directly.
I am somewhat familiar with the CMD Module which allows me to create simple commands that do the things that I want, but how can I integrate my gui texteditor and a CMD module console?

A similar idea can be found in 
[Integration of Python console into a GUI C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038247/integration-of-python-console-into-a-gui-c-application)
only difference is that I don't want a full python interpreter,and i'm not using C++

Any suggestions

Comment: You want a REPL? (Read,Eval,Print then Loop)

Comment: Yeah I guess. Just to be clear I will code the commands that are available from the console. So I may have a function that creates a table in the sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found
http://obswww.unige.ch/~revaz/git/old.glups-4.0/glups/pycutext.py

This module implements a QT4 python interpreter widget.
It is inspired bu PyCute : http://gerard.vermeulen.free.fr

I cannot take credit for the solution, but it effectively redirects all python stdin,stdout and even stderr to the pyQt Widget. Its exactly what I was looking for.